# Add to cart validation based on product attribute in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm trying to add a filter when a customer adds a product to the cart, to allow it or not.

We just need to compare one attribute of the WooCommerce products.

- If cart is empty : Add to cart ok
- If cart has 1 or more items : check Attribute XXX value of products
- If Attribute value is the same :  Add to cart ok
- If Attribute value is different : Add to cart denied and message will display

I have this code so far, but it doesn't work well at all, and I'm unsure why?

```php
// Check Products added to cart for same vendor
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id ) {

  global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

  foreach($items as $item => $values)
        {
          $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
          $prod1_vendeur[] = $_product->get_attribute( 'pa_vendeur' );
        }

  $newproduct = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  $prod2_vendeur = $newproduct->get_attribute( 'pa_vendeur' );

  if (isset($prod1_vendeur ))
  {
    if ( $prod1_vendeur[0] != $prod2_vendeur )
      {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( 'Error message' , 'notice' );
      }
  }
  return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

Any help is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- While you specify that the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook contains 5 arguments, you pass only 2
- `global $woocommerce;` is not necessary, use `WC()` instead

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {   
    // Setting
    $attribute = 'pa_vendeur';
    
    // Real product ID
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    
    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    
    // Get the product attribute value
    $product_attribute = $product->get_attribute( $attribute );
    
    // Initialize
    $flag = false;
    
    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get cart
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        
        // If cart is NOT empty
        if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {
            // Loop through cart items
            foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                // Get the product attribute value
                $cart_item_attribute = $cart_item['data']->get_attribute( $attribute );
                
                // NOT equal
                if ( $cart_item_attribute != $product_attribute ) {
                    // Flag becomes true
                    $flag = true;
                    
                    // Break loop
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( __( 'My custom error message', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works perfect with single products, but seems to have issues if products on the cart is a variable product...

Comment: Now it works only with variable products :) If I add a single product, error message shows... Maybe I need a big IF to separate single from variable products cases ?

Comment: For me it works for both products (simple & variable). Nothing stops you from trying to adapt it to your needs. After all, the intention is that you will learn something from it yourself, not that someone else does it all for you. Regards

Comment: Trying my best to find out, I already learned a lot in the last 3 days trying to do it :) But still looking where the small bug with variable products come from... Thanks a lot for your help !